# Changing header height on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, padding

I have [this](http://prntscr.com/iys04r) busiprof [theme](https://pt.wordpress.org/themes/busiprof/) based [site](http://www.formacaodmsti.pt/) and I wish to change the padding in the header to [100 pixels](http://prntscr.com/iyrzw8) (this is the size I want to achieve)

Since I can't edit the header height on the Appearance tab on Wordpress, how do I change it?  Keep In mind that I'm new to Wordpress, HTML and CSS.
Thanks

Comment: It's a bit of a difficult question to answer without knowing the theme itself. If may have an option for for header height, or a place for custom css. I suggest you google working with child themes in wordpress, as there is no simple answer to your question.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, this is the theme https://pt.wordpress.org/themes/busiprof/

Comment: I cannot install the theme to fix your problem. However, looking at your site, it looks like changing your logo width will fix the problem. This can be done in css, or perhaps edit the image and change it's width to 200px. As I mentioned before, it would be easy to do in a child theme. If you wish to do your own websites you should really look into child themes, and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo width on the site is causing the logo and menu to wrap, hence the height of 200. Change the image width to 200px will stop the wrap, and change the header height to 100px.

I tested this using the chrome console, and it worked.